# Normalized state in Bloc flutter

Tags: flutter, redux, bloc, flutter-bloc

Like everyone, I am also confused about statemanagement in Flutter, but I really like Bloc and the [library](https://github.com/felangel/bloc). But one thing is not clear. I read all the docs and all the tutorials already!

I come from redux where you have one big global store, in which you have normalized states. I don't know if I should or how I should correlate redux to bloc, but they felt similar from the beginning and they still do. You have a state, events and you listen to state change and trigger events..

Say I have an app where I have events, I might create, list an event show it in a screen, in another screen etc. I might fetch and cache an event. Doesn't this require me to have a normalized state somewhere? And where?

Normalized state is basically having a single place for storing an object, like storing it in a map, and referring to that object in other places by id, then using the map to show the object in the UI

So where should I put normalized state in Flutter? In a bloc? In a bloc high up in thr tree? In the repository? Should I use normalized state at all or is there another way to think about this?
Thank you!